# Need pagination on Aggreration Groupping Elastic search

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

We have applying aggregation and grouping, Need pagination for this.

```
 let body = {
      size: item_per_page,
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [{
            "terms": {
              "log_action_master_id": action_type
            }
          }, {
            "match": {
              [search_by]: searchParams.user_id
            }
          }, {
            "match": {
              "unit_id": searchParams.unit_id
            }
          },
          {
            "range": {
              [search_date]: {
                gte: from,
                lte: to
              }
            }

          }
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "group": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "id",
            "size": item_per_page,
            "order": { "_key": sortdirction }

          },
        },
        "types_count": {
          "value_count": {
            "field": "id.keyword"
          }
        },
      },
    };
```

Comment: are you trying to paginate aggregation result?

Comment: I have tried, but not success What is the method for applying pagination?

Answer (score 1):

You can use below options:-

1. [Composite Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html): can combine **multiple datasources** in a single buckets and allow pagination and sorting on it. It can only paginate linearly using after_key i.e you cannot jump from page 1 to page 3. You can fetch "n" records , then pass returned after key and fetch next "n" records.

```
GET index22/_search
{
 "size": 0,
 "aggs": {
   "ValueCount": {
     "value_count": {
       "field": "id.keyword"
     }
   },
   "pagination": {
     "composite": {
       "size": 2,
       "sources": [
         {
           "TradeRef": {
             "terms": {
               "field": "id.keyword"
             }
           }
         }
       ]
     }
   }
 }
}
```

2. [Include partition](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_with_partitions): group's the field’s values into a number of partitions at query-time and processing only one partition in each request. Term fields are evenly distributed in different partitions. So you must know number of terms beforehand. You can use [cardinality aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html) to get count

```
GET index22/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "TradeRef": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "id.keyword",
        "include": {
          "partition": 0,
          "num_partitions": 3
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

3. [Bucket Sort aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-sort-aggregation.html)  : sorts the buckets of its parents multi bucket aggreation. Each bucket may be sorted based on its _key, _count or its sub-aggregations. It only applies to buckets returned from parent aggregation. You will need to set term size to 10,000(max value) and truncate buckets in bucket_sort. You can paginate using from and size just like in query. If you have terms more that 10,000 you won't be able to use it since it only selects from buckets returned by term.

```
GET index22/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "valueCount":{
      "value_count": {
        "field": "TradeRef.keyword"
      }
    },
    "TradeRef": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "TradeRef.keyword",
        "size": 10000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "my_bucket": {
          "bucket_sort": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "_key": {
                  "order": "asc"
                }
              }
            ],
            "from": 2, 
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In terms of performance composite aggregation is a better choice

Comment: The include partition query structure does not sort correctly. Data sorted after dividing data. I don't think there is a query structure that can paginate a data with more than 65536 items and go to the page you want.