# Can I do a query that has both distinct and field and pagination it in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, pagination, distinct-values

A query that **distinct a field** and implement **pagination** in ElasticSearch. I am aware of these problems implement separated but we search a solution that implement tow feature together . I attach codes that we try to use them .
***1.implemet pagination only :***

```
POST myIndex/_search
{
  "from": 2,
  "size": 5,
  .
  .
  .
}
```

***2.implement distinct one field in my query***

```
POST myIndex/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "myField": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name’s of my field",
        "size": 10000
      }
    }
  }
.
.
.
}
```

***3.implement distinct field and pagination together***

```
POST myIndex/_search
{
  "from":2 
  "size": 5,
  "aggs": {
    "myField": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name’s of my field",
        "size": 10000
      }
    }
  }
.
.
.
}
```

4. As you observe codes , when we try using distinct and pagination together we can’t change value of first size (in distinct a field first value must be zero) and second value doesn’t have effect. Also I try to use partition but I can’t have any result .

```
POST myIndex/_search
{
  "from":2 
  "size": 5,
  "aggs": {
    "myField": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name’s of my field",
        "include": {
              "partition": 0,
              "num_partitions": 20
            },
        "size": 10000
      }
    }
  }
.
.
.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try elastic search [collapsing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/collapse-search-results.html)

```
GET index-name/_search
{
  "collapse": {
    "field": "field-name"
  },
  "from":0,
  "size": 5
}
```

For pagination in aggregation

check this [Need pagination on Aggreration Groupping Elastic search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58638205/need-pagination-on-aggreration-groupping-elastic-search)

Comment: I run this code but return error :`{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "request does not support [collapse]",
        "line" : 2,
        "col" : 3
      }
    ],
    "type" : "parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "request does not support [collapse]",
    "line" : 2,
    "col" : 3
  },
  "status" : 400
}`

Comment: @s.h.moghaddasi what is your elastic search version